# Need to set up diiferent java versions to run both android studio and bamboo

Tags: java

On the server I have 2 versions of java, 8 and 11. 11 is the default, it is needed for android studio to work. To run the bamboo agent, I need 8. How to choose version 8 for bamboo and leave 11 as standard so as not to change them all the time

Comment: Why can't you directly launch Bamboo by explicitly using the Java 8 instead of by java home path?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `conf/wrapper.conf` file and change the Java Application to something like:

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java
```

and then restart your agent.